# Pointers vs Relations JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Javascript SDK of Parse.
I need help with the given scenario.

I have a 'Debate' class and a 'User' class (Parse.User). I want to store a list of User objects in a column(column name: users) in 'Debate'.

What would be the best way to do it? Relations or Pointer Columns. 
Please provide a pseudo code as the SDK guide isn't very descriptive.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a list of Users objects in a column, you should be using an [Array](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#relations-using-arrays):

```
// let's say we have four users
var user1 = ...
var user2 = ...
var user3 = ...
var user4 = ...

// stick the objects in an array
var users = [user1, user2, user3, user4];

// store the users for the debate
var debate = ...
debate.set("users", users);
```

Comment: When creating the column "users" in Debate class, what type would you suggest to be the best? Currently I have set Pointer(_User). Could you suggest anything better or this code sample would work with that?

http://snag.gy/gL5Yl.jpg

Comment: @Pranav probably an array. Maybe relation, but not sure!